# Pygame with Smartboard Event Type

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I want know what the correct event type for a electronic smart white board is, at the moment the following works on a regular screen with mouse, and with a mouse attached to a electronic white board, but it doesn't respond to the finger tap.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
```

What is the correct event.type for smart boards when using your finger to tap the white board.

Comment: Maybe you just write a little application that does nothing but print out every event it recieves? This way you could see if there's an event at all.

Comment: So use: pygame.event.get(): and blit it to screen and change the event type to whatever the event is?

Comment: Just use something like `for e in pygame.event.get(): print e` and watch in the console window what happens if you tap the white board.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my code and it prints out the event type to the terminal.

```
event = pygame.event.poll()
x = event.type
print pygame.event.event_name(x)
```

Comment: Did you find out the correct event? Which one was it?